# Visual Studio Code no me reconoce la ruta de las imagenes locales

Tags: javascript, imagen, vscode, rutas

Compañeros buenas a todos, tengo un problema con visual Studio Code en el reconocimiento de las rutas de unas imágenes en una carpeta. Intente entrar a la ruta de varías formas como ustedes podrán comprobar en las imágenes pero al visualizar la pagina en el navegador no me aparecen. Ocurre que este proyecto lo intente hacer por mi cuenta, pero al ver que no me cargaban las imagenes decidí clonar el proyecto de un repositorio del cual me base y al visualizar esté en mi navegador, este funciona pero el que yo estába haciendo por mi cuenta no, como ultima opción pase todo el codigo del proyecto original al mio, pero al visualizarlo desde la carpeta en donde está mi proyecto tampoco funciona, ni siquiera teniendo el codigo exacto del original :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto aparece en el navegador: no me cargan las imágenes en el slider
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo tener todo el código bien, lo he revisado muchas veces. Si a alguien más le ha pasado agradezco mucha una respuesta

Comment: Asegúrate que en tu archivo donde inicializas el servidor tengas el codigo para que los HTML reconozcan las rutas ejemplo `app.use("/src", express.static(__dirname + '/src'));`

Comment: No pongas capturas de pantalla, pone el codigo. ¿como estas ejecutando tu app?, ¿intentaste utilizar otros nombres para las propiedades?, ¿intentaste levantar directamente la imagen con la misma ruta?, como sabes que el inconveniente es la imagen y no la funcion que utilizas para llamarla, ¿que mensaje de error recibis en la consola?

Comment: Quita la / del inicio de las rutas, que eso les dice que empieza desde la raiz.
O usa ./src/assets/imagen.jpg

Answer (score 0):

lo resolví descargando la extension Path Intellisense